# OptaPlanner ignoring constraint

Tags: java, optaplanner, constraint-programming

I created a `timeToIdealDate` constraint in VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider.

- **The goal of this constraint** is to group *visits* to *vehicles* with the visit's `idealDate` being closest to the vehicle's `start` date.
- **The issue I'm having** it doesn't matter which dates are assigned to `start` and `idealDate`. It seems like the visits are randomly assigned to vehicles, ignoring the soft constraint.
- **What I'm expecting** is for the solver to switch visits from one vehicle to the next until the score becomes lower and lower due to `start` date being closer to the sum of all idealDate` for the vehicle.

Any ideas?

### Example

Given we have "Vehicle A" with start date of `2022-01-05` and "Vehicle B" with start date of `2022-10-05`. A visit with idealDate `2022-11-23` should be assigned to "Vehicle B".

### Sample Dataset

- 5 vehicles (`start` date spread out throughout a single year)
- 30 visits (`idealDate` randomly spread throughout a single year)

### Main Data

**PlanningVisit has `idealDate`:**

- The ideal target date for when a vehicle would visit the location
- Format: unix timestamp in seconds

**PlanningVehicle has `start`:**

- The date the vehicle would leave the depot
- Format: unix timestamp in seconds

### Code Snippets

`vehiclerouting/plugin/planner/VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider.java`:

```java
package org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner;

import static org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors.sumLong;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoftlong.HardMediumSoftLongScore;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Constraint;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintFactory;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintProvider;
import org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.domain.PlanningVisit;

public class VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                vehicleCapacity(constraintFactory),
                timeToIdealDate(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    Constraint vehicleCapacity(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(PlanningVisit.class)
                .groupBy(PlanningVisit::getVehicle, sum(PlanningVisit::getDemand))
                .filter((vehicle, demand) -> demand > vehicle.getCapacity())
                .penalizeLong(
                        "vehicle capacity",
                        HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD,
                        (vehicle, demand) -> demand - vehicle.getCapacity());
    }

    Constraint timeToIdealDate(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(PlanningVisit.class)
                .penalizeLong(
                        "time to ideal date",
                        HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
                        PlanningVisit::absoluteDistanceToIdealDate);
    }
}
```

`vehiclerouting/plugin/planner/domain/PlanningVisit.java`:

```java
package org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.domain;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.AnchorShadowVariable;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariableGraphType;
import org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.weight.DepotAngleVisitDifficultyWeightFactory;

@PlanningEntity(difficultyWeightFactoryClass = DepotAngleVisitDifficultyWeightFactory.class)
public class PlanningVisit implements Standstill {

    @PlanningId
    private long id;
    private PlanningLocation location;
    private int idealDate;

    // Planning variable: changes during planning, between score calculations.
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "vehicleRange", "visitRange" },
            graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    private Standstill previousStandstill;

    // Shadow variables
    private PlanningVisit nextVisit;
    @AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousStandstill")
    private PlanningVehicle vehicle;

    PlanningVisit() {
        // Hide public constructor in favor of the factory.
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanningLocation getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(PlanningLocation location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getIdealDate() {
        return idealDate;
    }

    public void setIdealDate(int idealDate) {
        this.idealDate = idealDate;
    }

    public Standstill getPreviousStandstill() {
        return previousStandstill;
    }

    public void setPreviousStandstill(Standstill previousStandstill) {
        this.previousStandstill = previousStandstill;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanningVisit getNextVisit() {
        return nextVisit;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextVisit(PlanningVisit nextVisit) {
        this.nextVisit = nextVisit;
    }

    public PlanningVehicle getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(PlanningVehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Complex methods
    // ************************************************************************

    /**
     * Distance from the previous standstill to this visit. This is used to calculate the travel cost of a chain
     * beginning with a vehicle (at a depot) and ending with the {@link #isLast() last} visit.
     * The chain ends with a visit, not a depot so the cost of returning from the last visit back to the depot
     * has to be added in a separate step using {@link #distanceToDepot()}.
     *
     * @return distance from previous standstill to this visit
     */
    public long distanceFromPreviousStandstill() {
        if (previousStandstill == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "This method must not be called when the previousStandstill (null) is not initialized yet.");
        }
        return previousStandstill.getLocation().distanceTo(location);
    }

    /**
     * Distance from this visit back to the depot.
     *
     * @return distance from this visit back its vehicle's depot
     */
    public long distanceToDepot() {
        return location.distanceTo(vehicle.getLocation());
    }

    public long absoluteDistanceToIdealDate() {
        long vehicleStart = vehicle.getStart();
        if (idealDate > 0 && vehicleStart > 0) {
            return Math.abs(idealDate - vehicleStart);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Whether this visit is the last in a chain.
     *
     * @return true, if this visit has no {@link #getNextVisit() next} visit
     */
    public boolean isLast() {
        return nextVisit == null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlanningVisit{" +
                (location == null ? "" : "location=" + location.getId()) +
                ",demand=" + demand +
                ",idealDate=" + idealDate +
                (previousStandstill == null ? "" : ",previousStandstill='" + previousStandstill.getLocation().getId()) +
                (nextVisit == null ? "" : ",nextVisit=" + nextVisit.getId()) +
                (vehicle == null ? "" : ",vehicle=" + vehicle.getId()) +
                ",id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`vehiclerouting/plugin/planner/domain/PlanningVehicle.java`:

```java
package org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.domain;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;

public class PlanningVehicle implements Standstill {

    @PlanningId
    private long id;
    private int capacity;
    private int start;
    private PlanningDepot depot;

    // Shadow variables
    private PlanningVisit nextVisit;

    PlanningVehicle() {
        // Hide public constructor in favor of the factory.
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public PlanningDepot getDepot() {
        return depot;
    }

    public void setDepot(PlanningDepot depot) {
        this.depot = depot;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanningVisit getNextVisit() {
        return nextVisit;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextVisit(PlanningVisit nextVisit) {
        this.nextVisit = nextVisit;
    }

    public Iterable<PlanningVisit> getFutureVisits() {
        return () -> new Iterator<PlanningVisit>() {
            PlanningVisit nextVisit = getNextVisit();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextVisit != null;
            }

            @Override
            public PlanningVisit next() {
                if (nextVisit == null) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                PlanningVisit out = nextVisit;
                nextVisit = nextVisit.getNextVisit();
                return out;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PlanningLocation getLocation() {
        return depot.getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlanningVehicle{" +
                "start=" + start +
                "capacity=" + capacity +
                (depot == null ? "" : ",depot=" + depot.getId()) +
                (nextVisit == null ? "" : ",nextVisit=" + nextVisit.getId()) +
                ",id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `timeToIdealDate` constraint looks right, even though it can be simplified by removing the `groupBy()` and passing the `PlanningVisit::absoluteDistanceToIdealDate` directly to the `penalizeLong()`:

```
Constraint timeToIdealDate(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(PlanningVisit.class)
                .penalizeLong(
                        "time to ideal date",
                        HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
                        PlanningVisit::absoluteDistanceToIdealDate);
    }
}
```

As far as debugging constraints is concerned, the following steps could help:

- create a small dataset that can be visually checked by a human being
- implement a [ConstraintProviderTest](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/optaplanner-examples/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/score/VehicleRoutingConstraintProviderTest.java)
- temporarily disable other constraints

Comment: Thanks for the tip of not needing groupBy. I do get the same score without it. I could try implementing a ConstraintProviderTest. 

It however still seems as though the soft score never seems to lower, and visits are assigned "randomly". From [this log](https://gist.github.com/patricknomad/1a7f74c8344454a9a90c7a33c5a461d2) it seems like the solver is changing vehicles but the score doesn't change.

Comment: With just two constraints, you are not giving the solver many options for differentiation. It will first minimize the hard score and, having done that, it is probably hard to find a better soft score while keeping the same hard score. If you think the solver is stuck in a local optima, consider adding some extra move types. But introducing new soft constraints may actually help the solver to find a better path through the search space.